# VB.net WebBrowser is Locking Office Files Preventing Deletion

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, locking, webbrowser-control

I'm displaying pdf's and office documents in webBrowser controls. The files are stored in a zip file and extracted to the app directory before they are displayed in the webbrowser. When the application is closed I want to delete any files that have been extracted to clean up the app directory.

When a file is displayed by the user I'm adding the browser to a list to keep track of what's been opened. When the application closes, I want to release any references to the opened files, the following works with pdf's but not office files:

```
  Private OpenedFiles As New List(Of WebBrowser)
```

Adding a Browser:

```
  Dim browser As WebBrowser
  browser.Navigate(FilePath)
  OpenedFiles.Add(browser)
```

Form Closing event:

```
  For Each myBrowser As WebBrowser In OpenedFiles 
      myBrowser.DocumentText = ""
      myBrowser.Navigate("about:blank")
  Next
```

When this code has executed any opened pdf's can be deleted, but any office files cannot and the office application remains running in task manager.

Please can someone suggest how I can close and then delete the office files.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebBrowser control implements IDisposable so you should call .Dispose on each one when your form closes. That should clean up an resources and file handles:

```
For Each myBrowser As WebBrowser In OpenedFiles 
   myBrowser.Dispose()
Next
```

Comment: Hi Matt, works with ppt and xls so good enough for me, thanks very much